# Can not able to store data on mongoDB with Angular,js and Node,js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I am learning the MEAN stack. As I was trying to execute the basic program where I am storing HTML form data mongoDB by using Angular.js and node.js. But I am getting error and I am not able solve it.

console output:

> clicked submit
>
> index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/blah.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> angular.min.js:123 Possibly unhandled rejection:
>   {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8080/blah","data":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain,
>   */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}

I am posting code of html file, angular js file and node.js file

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Author:
      <input type="text" ng-model="author">
      <br>
      <br> Title:
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <br>
      <br> Body:
      <input type="author" ng-model="body">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.data = {};
$scope.submit= function(){
    console.log('clicked submit');
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/blah',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $scope.data
    }).then(function (httpResponse) {
        console.log('response:', httpResponse);
    })
   }
 });
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;


//const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';

var port = 8080;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/blah', function(req, res, next){
  var cope = req.body.params;
  db.collection('book').insert(cope, (err, result) => {
    if (err) 
    { 
      res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }); 
    } 
    else 
    {
      res.send(result.ops[0]);
    }

  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Is your index.html rendered from backend? how your website url starts with: `http` or with `file`

Comment: File@kaxi1993 I am not rendering it form backend.

Comment: Thats why you receive CORS problem Jay Tanna

Comment: @kaxi1993 What to do now? Guide me

Answer (score 0):

Render `index.html` from server add this code in your `server.js` file

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('/absolute/path/to/index.html');
});
```

and add slash to your scripts paths in `index.html`

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

no visit http://localhost:8080 and you will see your file send post request from here

```
<form ng-submit="submit($event)">
  Author:
  <input type="text" ng-model="author">
  <br>
  <br> Title:
  <input type="text" ng-model="title">
  <br>
  <br> Body:
  <input type="author" ng-model="body">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

app.js

```
$scope.submit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $http({
    url: '/blah',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $scope.data
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    console.log('response:', httpResponse);
  })
});
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Now this error is showing up

Comment: you need to change url: `/absolute/path/to` for your index.html file I don't know what exactly it is so that added this for test

Comment: Yes I have changed that and index.html is showing up no issues in this but after pressing submit button url changes to [link]http://localhost:8080/?

Comment: try this: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit($event)">`
and in app.js $scope.submit= function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...

Comment: No it is not solving the problem